# retrieve data with a proc print or a sql query or else

Tags: sql, sas

I'm looking for advice on that one. Some context before.

I have the following table on SAS. There are 711 observations and many more variables. Below is a sample from my table.

```
date     col1 col2 col3
jun14     0    0    0
may14     1    0    2
apr14     1    0    3
```

The table has no index, no primary key , nothing.

The results I'm aiming for, is to know for a specific date, all the values of that column.

```
date     col1 col2 col3
may14     1    0    2
apr14     1    0    3
```

Example for May 14, I will have

I'm running the following SQL query on it

```
proc sql;
select * from mytable where date < (input('may14',MONYY5.));
```

As you can imagine, the query is heavy when you have many variables and many observations. The query started 50 minutes ago and it is still running.

I also thought about using a `proc print`

```
proc print data=mytable;
var date col1 col2 col3;
where date = (input('may14',MONYY5.));
run;
```

So here is my question.

Is there an other way to have my results rather than through this query or the proc print? Do I need to have a datastep like a transpose , although if I'm doing a transpose, things would be different (see below).

```
date jun14 may14 apr14 
col1 0     1     1
col2 0     0     0
col3 0     2     3
```

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: how many variables is "many more?"  As @vasja says, the missing `QUIT;` will make it look like PROC SQL is still running.

Comment: Hi DomPazz, is it relevant that I have 6000 variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you just missing `QUIT;` after `select` statement to end `PROC SQL`? I can't believe this could take such time for 771 records.

EDIT:

So the problem is in creating and displaying output directly in SAS windows.

Below log from my test with PROC PRINTTO to direct output to text file.
Takes less than 10 seconds.
The size of file is 100MB for 1000 records and 10000 variables.

Obviously, is would make more sense to output data to some other formats.
Also, what's the use of presenting thousands of values to the user?

```
114  data mytable ;
115     format date date9.;
116     array var  {10000};
117     do i=1 to 10000;
118        var(i)=i;
NOTE: The array var has the same name as a SAS-supplied or user-defined function.  Parentheses
      following this name are treated as array references and not function references.
119     end;
120     do i=1 to 1000;
121        date = i;
122        output;
123     end;
124  run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.MYTABLE has 1000 observations and 10002 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.13 seconds
      cpu time            0.12 seconds


125
126  ods html close;* no html output;
127  ods listing; *text output rather;
128
129  proc printto print="E:\sasoutput.lst";run;

NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


129!                                           * output to file;
130  proc sql;
131  select * from mytable where date < '1may2014'd;
132  ;
133  quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           9.35 seconds
      cpu time            8.57 seconds


134
135  %put &SQLOBS;
1000
```